# Forward movement while rotating lead to flickering

Tags: unity, c#, rotation

I'm trying to make a ship move forward while also turning, but when I start to play, the ship flickers when it tries to move and turn at the same time.

[image: ship flickering]

(as comments suggested, I added other code for the update method)

In the `FixedUpdate()`, there is first the turn update:

```
// maxTurn states how much at largest the ship could turn per update,
// it is set as 0.15f in this case. 
// stepTurn is the increment, set as 0.001f here. 
if (moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>().x > 0 && currentTurn < maxTurn)
    currentTurn += stepTurn;
else if (moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>().x < 0 && currentTurn > -maxTurn) 
    currentTurn -= stepTurn;

else { // No key pressed, restablizing into no rudder 
    if (Mathf.Abs(currentTurn) > stepTurn)
        currentTurn = Mathf.Sign(currentTurn) * (Mathf.Abs(currentTurn) - stepTurn * TRANQUILIZER);
        // gradually reduce the turn rate
        // TRANQUILIZER is 0.99
    else // If turn rate is smaller than a threshold, mark it zero
        currentTurn = 0;
}
```

Followed by movement distance update:

```
if (moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>().y > 0)
    currentSpeedZ += stepSpeed;
else if (moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>().y < 0)
    currentSpeedZ -= stepSpeed;

// Keep the speed inside possible range
currentSpeedZ = Mathf.Clamp(currentSpeedZ, maxSpeedBack, maxSpeedFront);
// Unlike turning, forward movement remains even without pressing keys
```

After the calculations above, the ship is then turned around `Y` aixs and moved forward:

```
objectToMove.transform.Rotate(0, currentTurn, 0, Space.Self);

objectToMove.transform.position += objectToMove.transform.forward * currentSpeedZ;
```

What could have caused the flickering?

Other info in case needed:

- The forward movement speed is a constant while the flickering happens, represented as `currentSpeedZ` in the code above. Turning rate increases from zero while pressing the left and right arrow key, and drops back to zero after releasing. Represented as `currentTurn` in the code above.
- The ship is hard programmed to tilt slightly due to centrifuge force, but it is tested that the flickering still happens even if I turn off this tilting effect.
- Due to size limitation I cropped the gif, which made it harder to see that the ship is turning(the camera is at a fixed position right after the ship), but she is turning.
- The ship is roughly 16 units' length and 3 units' width. Modeled in Maya and then imported into Unity. No collision box is applied.

Comment: Have you checked if `currentTurn` is not flickering around its maximum value? Are you sure that turning and move forward are always applied in the same order - say turn first, move second?

Comment: Can you show us a full move function that demonstrates this effect, rather than two isolated lines? This will help us see how you're populating all the various inputs and the sequence in which you're performing each step. You should also include information about how the object is set up (does it have a Rigidbody or colliders, etc)

Comment: @Nikaas I added some extra `if` and made the ship's turn rate and speed remains unchanged (quite a trivia numerically, but quite long, so I did not update them into the question description) but this problem still happens. Also, the rotate and move are written in the same update method, I believe they would follow this execution order.

Comment: You can try removing `currentTurn`/`maxTurn` comparisons from the first 2 `if` and add `Mathf.Clamp(-maxTurn, maxTurn, currentTurn);` after the whole if statement. This will preven it from alternating between rising and lowering the turn value while at max turn limit.